# What does do_action('admin_init'); does actually?

Tags: 404-error

What impact does disabling do_action('admin_init'); in admin.php make? I disabled this function because Whenever i was trying to insert featured image, I get 404 error, i.e.  media-upload.php and ajax-admin.php was not found in the server.

After disabling do_action('admin_init'); , everything worked fine except admin design was gone. I then manually hooked colors-classic.css.

Thanks
Sabin

Answer (score 3):

What it does: It offers an action handler, a moment in run time to execute other functions.

So it is a hook for plugins and core functions. Removing all hooked functions or changing the core file **will** break WordPress.
If your plugin fails to work with it – fix the plugin.

Comment: I tried disabling all the plugins but in vain, thats why what i did was something i could to at last. The error was caused due to do_action("admin_init"). Disabling this function fixed the 404 error problem. But, still I know disabling this hooked function might make impact on the system.

Comment: Find out what exactly happens, don’t just delete random code. [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) or similar tools will tell you what goes wrong.

Comment: Okay i discoverd, this was due to APC installed in the server, I disabled APC using ini_set and fixed the problem Thanks for helping.